# Source code of default emulator's contact-book application in android with sdk-8

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

Where can I get the source-code of default contact-book application which can be accessed from AVD with Android 2.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts